# ScrowView layout

Tags: android

estou com um problema em questão ao layout ScrowView, tipo, tenho um formulário com 7 campos a serem preenchidos, porém ao aparecer o teclado para poder preencher as informações, os primeiros editText sobem, e o scrowview não sobe para eu poder visualiza-los impossibilitando assim o preenchimentos dos mesmos, alguém pode me explicar como resolvo isso?

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="CADASTRO ODONTEC"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        />
```

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="338dp"
        android:layout_height="338dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/fundolinearcada"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        tools:context="com.des.odontec.equipe.odontec.View.MainActivity_Login"
        android:weightSum="1"
        >



        <EditText

            android:id="@+id/nomeUsuario"
            android:layout_width="292dp"
            android:layout_height="43dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:hint="Digite seu nome"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:ellipsize="start"
            android:background="@drawable/edittextfundo"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:textColorHint="#696969"


            />



        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/emailUsuario"
            android:layout_width="292dp"
            android:layout_height="43dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:ellipsize="start"
            android:background="@drawable/edittextfundo"
            android:hint="Digite seu email"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:textColorHint="#696969"
            />


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/senhaUsuario"
            android:layout_width="292dp"
            android:layout_height="43dp"
            android:background="@drawable/edittextfundo"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:ellipsize="start"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:hint="Digite sua senha"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:textColorHint="#696969"
            />



        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/confirSenhaUsuario"
            android:layout_width="292dp"
            android:layout_height="43dp"
            android:background="@drawable/edittextfundo"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:ellipsize="start"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:hint="Confirmar senha"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:textColorHint="#696969"
            />



        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/estadoUsuario"
            android:layout_width="292dp"
            android:layout_height="43dp"
            android:background="@drawable/edittextfundo"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:ellipsize="start"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:hint="Estado"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:textColorHint="#696969"
            />


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/cidadeUsuario"
            android:layout_width="292dp"
            android:layout_height="43dp"
            android:background="@drawable/edittextfundo"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:ellipsize="start"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:hint="Cidade"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:textColorHint="#696969"
             />


    </LinearLayout>
```

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btSalvar"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_width="242dp"
        android:layout_height="37dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
        android:background="@drawable/botaoodontec"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:onClick="salvar"
        android:text="Salvar"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fl2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/transparencia"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progress"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />
    </FrameLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Victor,

Pra resolver esse problema, você deve ir no **AndroidManifest.xml** e alterar o registro da sua Activity lá, por exemplo:

```
<activity
    android:name=".NomeDaActivity"   
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
    android:theme="@style/AppThemeNoActionBar">
</activity>
```

Você deve adicionar a linha **android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"**

Dessa forma, o Java vai entender, que nessa Activity, quando o teclado virtual for aberto, a editText que foi clicado será empurrado pra cima do teclado.